# Getting Google Analytics reporting for a series of non-contiguous days?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a Google Analytics question that seemed simple but is now confusing the hell out of me. The client doesn't want data for a date range, but rather 27 individual dates. I can only seem to see ways to set date *ranges* , not a collection of individual dates. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can't select individual dates just only a single day or an interval.